# DirectAdmin startpackage on VPS change

Tags: vps

I have a VPS with DirectAdmin. When a new user is created, there are already some folders/files created. Where can I change the standard created files/folders? For example: I always want a robots.txt in the public_html folder, when I create a user.
How to make this possible?

Answer (score 0):

***You can follow these steps:***

1. First of all, you need **login to DirectAdmin panel by your admin
   account**
2. On Your Account section, click **File Manager**
3. Next, goto "**domains**" directory
4. Final, open "**default**" directory

Here you can add, or delete files in the "**default**" directory. For example, you can create a robots.txt file in the "default" directory. *The result,  when you add a new website, you always will get robots.txt file in public_html*